Writing an integer to string function
i'm trying to write a function that take an integer in this interval [0;1000] and return the string of it.
Like for 234 it would be "234". But it don't work i don't know why do someone have an idea why ?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* int_to_str(int input)
{
  char buffer[5];
  char* output;
  int input_temp;
  int count;
  
  input_temp = input;
  count = 4;
  
  while (count >= 0)
  {
    buffer[count] = '0';
    while (input_temp > pow(10, count))
    {
      input_temp -= pow(10, count);
      buffer[count] += 1;
    }
    count --;
  }
  output = NULL;
  output = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer) + 1));
  strcpy(output, buffer);
  return output;
}

I tested it with a printf, for 2 it returns 10000

See: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?.

Get rid of pow() (and <math.h>). This function does not need the floating-point complications.

You do not nul-terminate buffer. Using strlen with a character array that is not properly terminated, causes undefined behaviour.

Where do you set NUL byte to mark the end of the string?

You need to pay attention to the difference between '0' and '\0'. It's very important here!

Look closely how you use count. From using pow(10,count) I would assume, count is not the correct index to store the result.

You should really do some range checking on the input. And use unsigned to make sure the compiler doesn't allow stupid mistakes for passing negative values. And why use two buffer? Why not write the digits straight into the output? Even if there's only one digit in the input value, the possible waste will only be significant if you're doing hundreds of thousands of times.

This question is similar to: Converting int to char in C. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In addition to the problems (> vs. >=, wrong order) answered here, code also has these problems:
Weak pow()
Some pow() do not provide the exact expected result for pow(10, count).  Instead a value just less than a power of 10 is returned.  When this is used (compare, subtract) with an integer, the result causes an off-by-1.  (pow(10,4) might yield 9,999.9999...
Avoid floating point functions for an integer problem.
Missing '\0'
In forming the string, OP's code fails to assign a null character.
Be specific
"I tested it with a printf, for 2 it returns 10000" deserves to have the code posted that did this.
Assigning leading zero digits
Since with 234, OP wants "234", OP's algorithm assigned a thousands digit of "0", even when the value is less than 1,000.

Other points:
No need to limit buffer size to so small
Rather than char buffer[5];, consider a buffer that can handle all int.  Commonly this is 12 for "-2147483648".
Use protection
Even though the goal is for values [0,1000], better code would check as values outside the range [0,9999] produce garbage results.
.... or instead make the function work for all int.
Test for allocation failure
malloc() may return NULL and passing that to strcpy() is undefined behavior (UB).

Alternative
Code here to illustrates the idea: build from the least significant digit to most.
The below has extra features like an arbitrary base.  Thus it can be simplified given OP only needs 10.
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Enough room INT_MIN as a binary string.
#define MY_ITOA_BUF_SIZE (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 2)
#define MY_ITOA_BASE_MIN 2
#define MY_ITOA_BASE_MAX 36

// Negative values result in a string beginning with a '-' for all bases
//
char* my_itoa(int i, int base) {
  char buf[MY_ITOA_BUF_SIZE];
  char *p = &buf[sizeof buf - 1];  // Point to last array element.
  assert(base >= MY_ITOA_BASE_MIN && base <= MY_ITOA_BASE_MAX);

  *p = '\0';
  int value = i < 0 ? i : -i;  // negative absolute value
  do {
    div_t qr = div(value, base);
    *(--p) = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[-qr.rem];
    value = qr.quot;
  } while (value);

  if (i < 0) {
    *(--p) = '-';
  }

  size_t n_used = (size_t) (&buf[sizeof buf] - p);
  char *s = malloc(n_used);
  if (s) {
    strcpy(s, p);
  }
  return s;
}


You are using a larger index for more significant digits, which places them at the right end of the char array instead, essentially reversing the number.
Moreover, by using >, you will be off by one in the least significant digit. This can be fixed by changing the loop condition to input_temp >= pow(10, count).
